# C compiler cannot create executables when cross-compiling

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I am cross compiling on a Intel based Linux Ubuntu system under Windows 10 for an Intel i486 under QNX 6.5.0. One of the libraries is snappy, v.1.0.4. Copied i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0* tools (gcc, g++, ld, etc.) from the QNX system to the /usr/local/bin in Ubuntu. Then configure as ./configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0. Run make and get an error: C compiler cannot create executables when cross-compiling.

In config.log:

```
configure:2985: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:3007: result: yes
configure:3117: checking build system type
configure:3131: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:3151: checking host system type
configure:3164: result: i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0
configure:3196: checking for style of include used by make
configure:3224: result: GNU
configure:3254: checking for i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0-gcc
configure:3270: found /usr/local/bin/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0-gcc
configure:3281: result: i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0-gcc
configure:3550: checking for C compiler version
configure:3559: i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0-gcc --version >&5
configure:3572: $? = 1
configure:3592: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3614: i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0-gcc    conftest.c  >&5
configure:3618: $? = 1
configure:3656: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "snappy"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "snappy"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.4"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "snappy 1.0.4"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "snappy"
| #define VERSION "1.0.4"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3661: error: in `/home/kirill/eleveldb/c_src/snappy-1.0.4':
configure:3665: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Comment: What are the details about the issue in `config.log`?

Comment: *Copied i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0 tools (gcc, g++, ld, etc.) from the QNX system to the /usr/local/bin in Ubuntu* - this does not sound right. How do you know these will run on your Ubuntu at all?

Comment: `configure:3559: i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0-gcc --version >&5` this already failed with exit code 1. Try running `i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0-gcc --version` by hand and look at the error message it produces.

Comment: `*Try running i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0-gcc --version by hand*`

This works.

i486-pc-nto-qnx6.5.0-gcc (GCC) 4.4.2
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Ok, next step, try compiling the same hello world program by hand. Also look at the return code (`$?`) after running gcc.

Comment: `Ok, next step, try compiling the same hello world program by hand.` This part also works. Can compile and, when copy it to a QNX machine, it runs there.

Comment: There should be a detailed error message in the `config.log` file.

Comment: After I run manual compilation of a sample .c file, configure starts working. Although, make fails with an error.

Comment: `There should be a detailed error message in the config.log file` So far it provides only information quoted in the question. Showing the code that it tried to compile and that it didn't go through.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". -- You don't need to repeat the comment you refer to. This is not a forum, nor an email system. If you like to link, you might want to use the poster's name after an ampersand, like this @kirill. This also triggers a reminder to that poster. -- Also, please add new information by [edit]ing your question. Down here in the comments it will get lost.

Comment: So you are saying, you can compile and link the source shown manually without problems, but the configure script cannot? Did you see the object and/or executable files?

Comment: Eventually managed to compile, although not completely sure what triggered the success :) Set LDFLAGS with the path to the QNX libraries. After that ran manual compilation of the lines that gave an error, tweaking the options. And it compiled. After that also the general make went through. Now getting it all together with the Erlang part.

Comment: Since you know the solution now, please write an answer. This will help others researching on the same problem. You can come back to mark it, too. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works!